# What does this quote mean and how do you define it?

Tags: literature

“Better than to exaggerate, I have lessened in all things.” - La Relacíon

Comment: It might be better to include a little additional context for the quote. Is the original in English or is this a translation?

Comment: Is this the work of Álvar Núñez Cabeza de Vaca?

Comment: @HotLicks - Maybe one of his Relacíons.

Comment: @Cascabel - Sorry.  I took French not Spanish/Portuguese in school

Comment: @Jim _no problemo_ , as John Connor said. Tell the truth...I've said it wrong so many times I cannot even remember which is correct;)

Comment: @Cascabel - Ha!  And I see now that he was Spanish. For some reason I had it in my head he was Portuguese, but I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

On no evidence at all (I don't know Spanish) I suggest this is a clumsy translation of an original that says something like

> Rather than exaggerating I have understated everything.

Answer (score 1):

If we put the subject first we get:

> I have lessened in all things, better than to exaggerate.

The parallelism and elision/sluicing (basically, omitting) is tricky, but the question is: what does the author mean by *lessened?*

I would interpret it, given the antonym provided "*exaggerate*", to lessen here means to [**downplay**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downplay) or basically be [**humble**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humility).

This is the speakers way of saying, "Of everything I have told you, that is worst-case scenario; if you investigated my assertions, they would meet or exceed expectations. In my opinion, this is better than [talking it all up](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Talk%20you%20up) (to exaggerate)"

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any chance of exaggeration, he has purposely gone the other way and and "lessened" his statements.